# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dna' referenced before assignment in Flask

Tags: python, flask

It used to work before passing the dnalists from render_template. Did it occur for passing too much data? 
What could be wrong here?

**Python Code:**

```
def home():
    form = DNAForm()
    rna = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        dna = form.dna.data.upper()
        # nonlocal dna
        A = dna.count('A')
        C = dna.count('C')
        G = dna.count('G')
        T = dna.count('T')

        rnadata = dna.maketrans('ACGT','UGCA')
        rna = dna.translate(rnadata)
        dnalist = [
            {'A' : A},
            {'C' : C},
            {'G' : G},
            {'T' : T},
            ]
        # if you don't want the form to be filled with previous data
        form.dna.data = ''

    return render_template('index.html', form=form, rna = rna, dna=dna, dlists=dnalist)
```

**html template**

```
<h3>RNA</h3>
                <hr>
                {% if rna %}
                <h4>The DNA is: <span class="text-danger">{{ dn }}</span> </h4>
                <h4>The RNA is: <span class="text-danger">{{ rna }}</span> </h4>
                {% endif %}
                <h4>Total Number in DNA:</h4>
                <hr>
                {% for dl in dlists %}
                    {% for k,v in dl.items() %}
                        <h4>{{ k }} : <span class="text-danger">{{ v }}</span> </h4>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

is `False`, then `dna` will never be defined. So you'll get an error here:

```
return render_template('index.html', form=form, rna = rna, dna=dna, dlists=dnalist)
```

Make sure your form is validated on submission. Or you can define some default like `None` (but that's likely to cause some other issue down the line)

Comment: Thank you @rdas. I forgot to declare dna as None and dnalists to an empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

it happens when your if returns False.

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

as you can see in the structure of your code, when the if statement returns `False` the code goes directly to the return where it tries to make use of the dna variable that has not been set (because it is only set when the if returns `True`

to solve it you should either add an else statement or define the value of the dna variable to a dummy value before the beggining of the if. While you are at that, you should take a look at the dna_list variable as you might have the same problem with this one.

something like this:

```
rna = None
dna = None
dna_list = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
```

I hope I was able to put it in an understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

define dna=None after rna=None should fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks, @ANISH. FYI, also had to declare dnalists as an empty list before.